# How to select an open Excel file with different file ending name

Tags: vba, excel, syntax

I have an Excel Macro which look for specific file name `Jobs in Lab.xlsx` and copy to other macro file.

However, on certain event, the file naming may change to `Jobs in Lab (0 - 195).xlsx`.

How do I implement Excel Left Syntax into below VBA?

```
Sub Test()
    Windows("Jobs in Lab").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? In a folder?

Comment: it's already opened to desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIKE` operator.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "Jobs in Lab*" Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wb
End Sub
```

The code assumes that the file is opened in the same Excel instance.

**EDIT**:

However if you still want to use `LEFT` then you can use it like this. Notice the use of `Ucase`. It converts the text into upper case and then does a comparison. You can use `LCASE` as well.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If UCase(Left(wb.Name, 11)) = "JOBS IN LAB" Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, i can't seem to make it work. on the second example, when vba operated, it went until "If UCase(Left(wb.Name, 11)) = "JOBS IN LAB" Then" and then goes straight to "End If". then exit the vba.

Comment: If your file name starts with "Jobs in Lab", then the above will work :) You might also want to try `If UCase(Left(Trim(wb.Name), 11)) = "JOBS IN LAB" Then`

Comment: thanks, it appear that i have to open the "Job In Lab" first before opening the Excel Macro.

Comment: Yup. Why you want to check that without opening the file?

Comment: i didn't, actually i opened the macro first, then open the "Job In Lab". appear macro could not find the excel if i open the macro first.

Comment: The it should work if the `"JOBS IN LAB"` is opened in the same excel instance. Also is it `"JOBS IN LAB"` or `"JOB IN LAB"` as per your previous comment.

Comment: Hi @Siddharth Rout, the "Jobs in Lab" was created by another program to preview the data, it was not save yet(no need to save). the VBA you provide could not look the file name unless the file was save. it is like you open new XLS which default name is "Book1", and ask VBA to look it.